# Equivalence of positive semi-definite matrices

Tags: matrices

Why can I follow 
$$\sigma I - RB^{-1}R^\top \mbox{ is pos. semi-definite} \Leftrightarrow B- \frac{1}{\sigma}R^\top R \mbox{ is pos. semi-definite}  $$
having $ \sigma > 0$ and $R$ being an   upper triangle matrix?

**EDIT**: $B$ is positive definit and symmetric. $R$ originates from QR factorization ($R\neq 0$).

Comment: If $R$ is the zero matrix, this can't be true...

Comment: $R$ is an upper triangle matrix, so it is not zero. It originates from a QR factorization.

Comment: The zero matrix is an example of an upper triangular matrix.  Are you given the additional information that $R$ has only non-zero diagonals?

Comment: QR decomposition of a zero matrix is $0 = QR$, so in that case $R = Q^T0 = 0$. You need to be more specific about $R$ (or the matrix from which it came).

Comment: True story. I have provided additional information as an EDIT above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implication is false. Take $R=1$, $B=-1$, $\sigma=1$. The first equation writes $1+1=2>0$, yet the second one is $-1-1=-2<0$.

Another example is to take $R=0$ and $B$ negative definite.

**Edit** some thoughts on the second version of the question.

Assume that $\det R\ne 0$. Being positive semidefinite is equivalent to say $\forall u$
$$\sigma\|u\|^2-(B^{-1}R^Tu,R^Tu)\ge 0.$$
One can now take $v=R^Tu$ and say that we have $\forall v$
$$\sigma\|R^{-T}v\|^2-(B^{-1}v,v)\ge 0.$$
$B$ is positive definite, so it admits a $B^{-1/2}$ in the class of positive definte matrices, let's take $w=B^{-1/2}v$. Hence $\forall w$
$$\sigma\|R^{-T}B^{1/2}w\|^2-\|w\|^2\ge 0.$$
Now we can say that $w=Rz$ and write $\forall z$
$$\|R^{-T}B^{1/2}Rz\|^2-\frac 1\sigma\|Rw\|^2\ge 0,$$
which is equivalent to say that

$$R^TB^{1/2}R^{-1}R^{-T}B^{1/2}R -\frac 1\sigma R^TR $$is positive semidefinite.

Comment: Thanks, that is correct. I have updated the question with an additional EDIT. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Exactly, what I needed to get it. Thanks a lot!